# Will this electric air pump suit my tires and work for me?

Tags: pump

I have to buy air pump for bicycle, I saw [this one online on Walmart](https://www.walmart.com/ip/150PSI-Bike-Electric-Inflator-Bicycle-Cycle-Air-Pressure-Pump-Rechargeable-Cordless-Tire-Pump-MTB-Road-Bike-Motorcycle-Car-Air-Inflator-Power-Bank/973798361).

My bicycle tires have a pressure range between 30 and 50 psi.  Will this pump work, or should I buy mechanical one?

What are it's drawbacks?

[image]

Comment: I think the item is https://www.walmart.com/ip/150PSI-Bike-Electric-Inflator-Bicycle-Cycle-Air-Pressure-Pump-Rechargeable-Cordless-Tire-Pump-MTB-Road-Bike-Motorcycle-Car-Air-Inflator-Power-Bank/973798361 retailing at $50-$55 USD

Comment: Get a proper, reliable floor pump. A bicycle pump is really not something which can be enhanced by adding electronics.

Comment: IMO electrical bicycle pumps are generally superfluous except perhaps for professionals who work on a lot of bikes per day. Pumping manually isn't really that much work and doesn't take that long, especially if the tires aren't completely flat. With cheap pumps, getting a good air-tight fit on the valve can take longer than the actual pumping action. Especially floor pumps are comfortable and don't require much force if chosen correctly for the desired pressure (high pressure vs. high volume variant).

Comment: How can that fit around the spokes?

Comment: If you're riding a bike for exercise then don't be afraid of a manual pump. Electric pumps weigh more than equivalent manual pumps unless we're talking about a heavy duty shop pump. If you're unable to pedal and use an electric bike then it would make sense to have an electric pump.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I’d assume there is a piece of flexible hose which screws onto the pump?

Answer (score 16):

In my experience, batteries are frequently flat when you need them.   This unit has the likelyhood of sitting unused for months, going flat, and then being useless when you really need it.

I strongly suggest you get a manual mini-pump instead.  Sure it'll be slow, but its more likely to work when you need it.   High tech is not always appropriate.

---

Based on the cost, you could easily buy a nice minipump for in your pocket/bag while riding, AND have the luxury of a floor pump (aka a track pump) to leave at home for maintenance.

I personally carry a mini-floor pump on one bike.  Though I use the floor pump weekly for top-ups, I only use the mini pumps when something goes wrong (for me or someone else who didn't bring one! )

Adding USB doesn't make things better.

---

Here's a review of two electric air pumps.  https://cyclingtips.com/2020/03/xiaomi-mijia-vs-fumpa-electric-tire-inflators-reviewed/  Neither are the one you suggested, but the general points are still relevant.

> Neither are intended for riding with.

> noise and vibration

> 1 minute and 24 seconds to inflate a 700×25 mm tire to 80 psi,

> had me questioning why I don’t just reach for my floor pump

> recorded the Mi at 85 dB, while the Fumpa has a wake-the-neighbours 99 dB output. In both cases, you’ll want to reinflate your tires the night before you sneak out for your early-morning ride.

**Upshot** Buy a minipump for your pocket for emergencies, and a floor pump to keep at home.

Comment: And if it is indeed used as a power-bank, the risk of sitting idle or months is near zero, bu the risk it's empty because you just charged your phone from it is pretty big :D What about mini-pumps with CO2 cartridges?

Comment: @Mołot: “What about mini-pumps with CO2 cartridges?” I’ve never understood why they are so popular. A good mini pump (e.g. Lezyne Road Drive) is barely heavier (82g vs. 66g) and can easily inflate to 5 or 6bar with the huge advantage of being able to do it multiple times.

Comment: @Michael Some people don't have arm strength or simply time to do so. OP wanted electric pump, so maybe there's a reason.

Comment: "Adding USB doesn't make things better" –1

Comment: If a power bank is desirable, perhaps one of the several lights that serve as power banks would be a better choice.  The poster's use case would have to be considered, but for mine I've found it a good idea, as I generally don't spend long periods in the dark and the light function is really only needed for a half hour or so.  I've only used it as a power bank a couple times, though, so really not a big deal there either.

Comment: @Michael CO2 cartridges are useful because they take one tenth the space of a mini pump, not because of the weight.

Comment: @Matsemann: The dimensions are pretty much the same and a mini pump can be mounted to the frame and you never have to think about it again.

Comment: @Michael a mini pump can be mounted to the frame and you never have to think about it again until two weeks later when you have a light crash and the plastic mount breaks.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I don't know about yourself, but I don't think you're supposed to crash every 2 weeks...

Comment: CO<sub>2</sub> is also very fast, so its good for a race or a group ride where time is critical.  However they're finicky, cold, and expensive.  You could not reasonably use CO<sub>2</sub> for topping off your bike before a ride.  CO<sub>2</sub>  is also wasteful.  Pumps just take longer is their main downside.

Comment: @Michael I mounted a Road Morph to my frame and it failed a few thousand miles later from exposure to road debris which eventually found its way into the pump... The pump stays in my pannier now.

Answer (score 1):

These products are for car owners. Not useful for cyclists as a track  pump is lighter and easy to use

You might check out Topeak's digital pressure gauge if you want digital.
https://www.topeak.com/global/en/products/gauges/351-smartgauge-d2

The weight is 1/10 of these digital pumps, so you can easily carry it around .

But pump your own tyres.

Comment: While the 150 PSI rating is probably quite optimistic, the example unit is certainly intended for bicycles as well as cars, given the fourth word in the title.

Comment: I agree that some of these products are marketed for bicycle users, my point is more about the real market for home compressors, which is to inflate car tyres, which contain a larger volume of air. Of course any product can be made for any use case, but that doesn't make it sensible.

Comment: @Criggie to me the title looks more like SEO spam than a product that is intended or suitable for any purpose

Answer (score 1):

This expands slightly on Criggie's answer.

Cyclists typically have two separate pumps: a floor pump for inflation at home, and a mini pump or CO2 inflator that they take with them for emergency inflation on the road. Mini pumps take longer to inflate tires, rely a lot more on upper body strength, and usually lack a pressure gauge. Floor pumps lack these disadvantages, but they aren't portable.

Criggie linked to a review by [David Rome](https://cyclingtips.com/2020/03/xiaomi-mijia-vs-fumpa-electric-tire-inflators-reviewed/) on Cyclingtips which compared two products: a Fumpa electric inflator that's akin to a floor pump, and a Xiaomi version of the same. Fumpa is an Australian company, and [they claim](https://www.fumpapumps.com/faqs/) that the individual parts are sourced from Australia, China, Japan, Spain, and the United States. Xiaomi is a mainland Chinese company, and presumably its supply chain is all in mainland China. The Fumpa cost US$179, and the Xiaomi pump cost Dave US$45 shipped to Australia. As is obvious, these pumps are electrically operated, and they are programmable. Provided the pressure gauges are accurate (Dave contended that they both were), one can pre-program a desired inflation pressure for the pump.

In a [separate review](https://cyclingtips.com/2019/06/fumpa-and-minifumpa-electric-bicycle-pumps-review/), Rome examined the standard Fumpa and a mini version of the Fumpa. The mini Fumpa is akin to a mini pump, and could easily be carried on bike, albeit it isn't waterproof. Rome's conclusion was that the standard Fumpa was a good travel pump. He is a serious cyclist, and he frequently travels by plane. The standard Fumpa allows him to not pack a floor pump, or one of the slightly smaller travel variants of a floor pump. This is a considerable space savings. Alternatively, the article mentioned that race mechanics have frequently used battery-operated inflators to quickly inflate or adjust pressure on multiple tires.

Based on that, I'd contend that electric inflators are a niche product that some serious cyclists should think about buying. They do not appear to be a logical purchase for the average cyclist.

---

I was going to also say that these pumps are probably more complex than standard floor pumps. With more complex items, I'd argue that going to cheaper quality can frequently compromise the item. I believe we clearly see this with disc vs. rim brakes: many lower-quality mechanical disc brakes don't generate more braking force than a decent rim brake, and the mechanical disc brakes are more expensive to boot. The same is true with suspension components on many hybrid bicycles designed for casual users who mainly tide on paths or roads: it would be better to ditch the suspension, rely on the tires to cushion the ride, and upgrade to better components elsewhere.

That said, the Xiaomi pump that Rome reviewed seemed to be of adequate quality  during the review period despite the low price (and the Lixada pump is actually more expensive than the Xiaomi). It may be possible to build a small electric pump, at sufficient quality for a casual cyclist, at a reasonable price. I would still caution that the moving parts, especially the inflation parts, might not prove to be durable in time. Furthermore, the quality of the lithium ion battery might be subpar. With the same number of charge-discharge cycles, a good lithium ion battery should retain its maximum capacity better than a poor one. This might not be as much an issue if the OP usually leaves the pump plugged in (but NB: keeping your battery at maximum charge all the time actually compromises its service life). Thus, I'd second the recommendation that the OP get a basic mechanical floor pump.

Comment: Good summary except I think that Xiaomi are capable of sourcing 18650 cells that aren't terrible at moderate cost. The major cost saving for them is a lower voltage motor, and one less battery. If it's lighter built then the product may be less durable but that's not given necessarily . As regards such cells you can usually tear apart a product contajning them and replace the battery as manufacturers now just use commodity 18650s albeit sealed inside.

Comment: I mentioned that review because of the comments about noise and speed, etc, if they exist in a higher priced product then a cheap end one will likely have the same issues.